# How to load font in ffmpeg through google font

Tags: ffmpeg

how to load font file in FFmpeg through web google font?. I tried to use google font in the cmd, but it seems telling that no web font found. can anyone tell me whether we can load font through google font URL

```
ffmpeg -i test.png -i sample1.mp4 -y -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1230:692[scale1];[scale1]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate0];[0:v][rotate0]overlay=333.61:172.85[mediaoverlayout0];color=black@0:959x137[c1];[c1]setsar=1,drawtext=fontfile='http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v18/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-U1UpcaXcl0Aw.ttf':text='Double click to edit':fontsize=121.19999999999999:fontcolor=#1e8bc3:line_spacing=16.916000000000007,rotate=0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0):c=black@0[rottext1];[mediaoverlayout0][rottext1]overlay=x=207.52:y=271.076:shortest=1" -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 10 ok1.mp4
```

**Below are logs**

```
 built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndi
o --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-lib
ass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --e
nable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-l
ibvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable
-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'storage/test.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, 1 reference frame, rgba(pc), 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[h264 @ 0x59749c0] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'storage/sample1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.17.101
  Duration: 00:00:08.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 820 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(left), 1920x1080 (1920x1088), 578 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 
tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
-y: No such file or directory
[AVIOContext @ 0x597a480] Statistics: 10601 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 0x597a040] Statistics: 156922 bytes read, 2 seeks
```

Comment: Show the command you tried and the complete log.

Comment: ffmpeg -i test.png -i sample1.mp4  -y -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1230:692[scale1];[scale1]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate0];[0:v][rotate0]overlay=333.61:172.85[mediaoverlayout0];color=black@0:959x137[c1];[c1]setsar=1,drawtext=fontfile='http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abeezee/v9/mE5BOuZKGln_Ex0uYKpIaw.ttf':text='Double click to edit':fontsize=121.19999999999999:fontcolor=#1e8bc3:line_spacing=16.916000000000007,rotate=0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0):c=black@0[rottext1];[mediaoverlayout0][rottext1]overlay=x=207.52:y=271.076:shortest=1" -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 10 ok1.mp4

please ignore rotate

Comment: I am getting following error 
[Parsed_drawtext_5 @ 0x7118480] Cannot find a valid font for the family Sans
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7104240] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile=http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abeezee/v9/mE5BOuZKGln_Ex0uYKpIaw.ttf:text=Double click to edit:fontsize=121.19999999999999:fontcolor=#1e8bc3:line_spacing=16.916000000000007'
Error initializing complex filters.
No such file or directory

Comment: Not possible. Download the font file first, then run ffmpeg.